# Wordpress posts to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter, integration

So i've been racking my head for the past week trying to get wordpress to autopost to Facebook and Twitter.

I have created a facebook page (just a sole page not linked to any profile), and a twitter account.

I've tried using ping.fm and ping.fm wordpress plugin. To post, I had to go into wordpress and manually make a ping.fm post, and it then gets sent to it's facebook/twitter. Twitter worked, facebook didn't, tried everything – it can't link to the facebook fan page. I gave up after 2 hours.

Does anyone have any other suggestions to link (automatically if possible) my wordpress posts to facebook fan page (timeline) and twitter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use online tools like below which will post from your blog to facebook.

- http://www.rssgraffiti.com/
- http://www.networkedblogs.com/

In addition to this, you can setup your facebook page to auto-post it to twitter. So, when you post a new article to facebook, the workflow will be 
Blog -> RSSGraffiti/Networkedblogs -> Facebook -> Facebook Auto post feature to Twitter -> Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is more than one way to auto post content from a WordPress post to social media.

I'd recommend having a look at one of the following options for auto posting

1. 1-click Retweet/Share/Like - It will auto post your WordPress posts to social media and provide like/share buttons on your post.
2. Jetpack Publicize - automatically post WordPress posts to social media
3. NextScripts: Social Networks Auto-Poster - auto post WordPress posts to social media
4. Dlvr.it - A 3d party which automatically takes your RSS feeds and post them to social media.

These are only a few methods, I believe searching the web will give you more options.

You can read this [blog](http://tribulant.com/blog/wordpress/how-to-post-from-wordpress-to-social-networks/) post if you need more info on auto posting.